# Iterator as key-type in an unordered_multimap

Tags: c++, stl, multimap

I want to create a map, that uses iterators as key-type and integers as values, like in the following example:

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  typedef std::list<int> ListType;
  typedef std::unordered_multimap<ListType::iterator, unsigned int> MapType;

  ListType _list;
  MapType _map;

  _list.push_back(100);
  _map.insert(std::make_pair(_list.begin(), 10));

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes the compiler aborting with the `error C2440: 'conversion' : cannot convert from 'const std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'size_t'`. Is there something i can do to achieve this anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to store an iterator as key? iterators might get invalidated as a result of operations you perform on the container.Though the chances that this happens for `std::list` are rare(erase operation),Hope you are aware of this fact.

Comment: I'm baffled as to why you'd want that, but you should probably pass a hashing function and equal testing function to the map.

Comment: @Als: Yes i'm aware of it, but i make sure, that this won't happen. I want to use this structure as a fast way to update another data-structure.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer: Hm... good point. I'll try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you have to provide a hash function for the particular iterator type. You can pass a hashing function as third template parameter to [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap).

`unordered_map` also requires an equality comparator for its keys, however std::list's iterator already has that, so you do not need to provide your own. For example:

```
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstddef>

typedef std::list<int> ListType;
typedef std::list<int>::iterator ListIterator;
// a very poor hashing functor
struct MyHash {
  size_t operator()(const ListIterator&) const {
    // provide a useful implementation here!
    size_t hash_ = .... ;
    return hash_;
    //return 0; // compiles, but is useless
  }
};

typedef std::unordered_multimap<ListIterator, unsigned int, MyHash> MapType;

int main() {

  ListType list_;
  MapType map_;

  list_.push_back(100);
  map_.insert(std::make_pair(list_.begin(), 10));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AquilaRapax I added an example.

Comment: Wow thanks, thats great an it works, but why? The pairs are inserted although the hashing-function is always returning 0. I will need to investigate on that, since i thought that hashing functions are very complex constructs... ;)

Comment: Why don't you just return `*it` or `&*it` from the hashing function, it's better than `0` anyway.

Comment: @AquilaRapax it works because hash structures are designed to cope with **collisions**, which are instances when two different keys produce the same hash. Hash functions are not unique, so the maps have to cope with this. In practice what will happen is that all your elements will be put in the same "bucket", so you will lose **all** the benefits of having a hash map.

Comment: @hamstergene returning `0` was just an example. It is not clear to me what a good hash function would be for this case. For example, all the elements of the list could be the same...

Comment: @AquilaRapax in case I wasn't clear, you definitely do not want to use the hash function I put in my example, you want to implement your own.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Very good explanation, thanks for that. I will seek for more informations about useful hash-functions.